# how to populate a select using .val()

Tags: jquery, select

I'm very new to jquery and having a hard time figuring this problem out.

I have 2 address forms, and the user has the choice of populating the second form with information from the first form. It works for all inputs but not selects.

Here is the line for selects:

```
    $('#shipstate').val($('#state option:selected').val());
```

I want this to: Take value of #state and set value of #shipstate.

I know that this alert below works and outputs the correct state, but I can't get the above line to then set the value of the second select.

```
alert($('#state option:selected').text());
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure you don't want `$('#shipstate').val($('#state option:selected').text());` then?

Comment: Adding a little example of what you are doing on jsfiddle.com or similar would help understand your problem and provide an optimal solution.

Comment: changing .val to .text leaves the second select with nothing selected and blank value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`option`'s `value` is *optional*. Might not be there.

you might want to get the current value of the actual `select`

```
$('#shipstate').val($('#state').val());
```

*(A simple demo (just to get the idea):)*

```js
$("#state").on('change', function(){
   $('#shipstate').val( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="shipstate" disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option> 
  </select>
  
  <select id="state">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option> 
  </select>
```